# Apache Commons Compress write from one stream to another hang up

Tags: java, android, compression, tar, apache-commons

I need to repack one tar archive to another. I know that ArchieveEntry is already a stream, so I'm simply write from one stream to another. Here's my code:

```
public void repack (String sourceFile, String destFile) throws IOException {

    TarArchiveInputStream tarIn = new TarArchiveInputStream (new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream (sourceFile)));
    TarArchiveOutputStream tarOut = new TarArchiveOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (destFile));

    TarArchiveEntry tarEntry;

    while ((tarEntry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry ()) != null) {

        tarOut.putArchiveEntry (tarEntry);

        if (tarEntry.isFile ()) {

            int counter;
            byte byteData[] = new byte[(int) tarEntry.getSize()];

            while ((counter = tarIn.read (byteData, 0, byteData.length)) != -1)
            tarOut.write (byteData, 0, counter);

        }

        tarOut.closeArchiveEntry ();

    }

    tarIn.close ();

    tarOut.flush ();
    tarOut.close ();

}
```

It show no errors, it's simply hang up. What is can be a broblem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe use `>0` instead of `!= -1`

Comment: @F43nd1r thanks, but no, streams always starting with 0, not 1, so zero is -1, not 0. Same with arrays.

Comment: Solve the problem by change the loop with `IOUtils.copy (tarIn, tarOut);`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int) returns the number of read bytes. 0 is a valid return value here, which will cause your loop to run infinite. The return value is not referring to an index. Streams may or may not use -1 as return value to indicate the of the stream.

Comment: However, as IOUtils is working, which uses -1 too, the original problem is probably your buffer size. You should always use a fixed buffer size.

Comment: If `tarEntry.getSize()` returns 0 you'll always ask `read` for 0 bytes which will always return 0 and you are inside an infinite loop.

Comment: @F43nd1r I tried 0, but with no result(

Comment: Ah, so interesting! Yes, I'm sure that `tarEntry.getSize()` have 0 value in some cases, but why `IOUtils.copy (tarIn, tarOut);` helps?

Comment: As I said, the problem is a variable buffer size (because it could be 0). IOUtils uses a fixed buffer size of `1024 * 4`. Reference http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java#IOUtils.copy%28java.io.InputStream%2Cjava.io.OutputStream%29

Answer (score 0):

Think the best way is to use `IOUtils.copy (tarIn, tarOut);`, I've just change the loop part of code to

```
if (tarEntry.isFile ())
IOUtils.copy (tarIn, tarOut);
```